# Sharing a TypedArray view of a SharedArrayBuffer with a worker - is the full SharedArrayBuffer accessible?

Tags: web-worker, sharedarraybuffer

If I create a `SharedArrayBuffer`, and then create a 'view' of said buffer via a `TypedArray`, and then send that `TypedArray` to a `Worker` via `postMessage`, is the worker able to access the full data of the `TypedArray`?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the full underlying buffer is shared with the web worker:

```html
<!-- test.html -->
<script>
  // Main thread
  const sharedBuffer = new SharedArrayBuffer(100); 
  const fullBuffer = new Uint8Array(sharedBuffer);
  fullBuffer.set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]); // Fill the start of the buffer with some data
  const partOfBuffer = new Uint8Array(sharedBuffer, 5); // Create a view that leaves off the first few numbers

  const worker = new Worker('worker.js');
  worker.postMessage(partOfBuffer);
</script>
```

```js
// worker.js
onmessage = function(e) {
  const partOfBuffer = e.data;
  console.log(new Uint8Array(partOfBuffer.buffer)); // logs the full buffer data - i.e. including the first few numbers
}
```